# Logical doubt about proof of sequential characterisation of compactness

Tags: real-analysis

I was studying a proof of the standard sequential characterisation on compactness, when I got trapped into one "logical" doubt concerning the proof.

---

*The following is the general setup.*

The proposition is the following:

> **Proposition:** A subset $S$ of a metric space $X$ is compact if, and only if, every sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $S$.

The proof starts with:

> *Proof:* Let $S$ be a compact subset of $X$, and $(x_m) \in S^\infty$ (*note: which denotes the set of all sequences on $S$*). Suppose that $(x_m)$ does not have a subsequence that converges in $S$. In that case, $T := \{ x_1, x_2, \dots \}$ must be a closed subset of $S$.

---

**Question:** Why is the case that $T$ is closed?

*My thoughts:*
We are assuming that 
$$\forall (x_{m_k})\subseteq (x_m) \ \big( x_{m_k} \to x \Longrightarrow x \notin S \big),$$
which also implies that $x \notin (x_m)$.

We know that $(x_m)$ is closed iff
$$ \forall (x_{m_k}) \subseteq (x_m) \ \big( x_{m_k} \to x \Longrightarrow x \in (x_m) \big),$$
that is equivalent to 
$$ \forall (x_{m_k}) \subseteq (x_m) \ \big( x \notin (x_m) \Longrightarrow x_{m_k} \nrightarrow x \big).$$

But, we are assuming by contradiction that $x \notin (x_m)$, hence we can conclude that $x_{m_k} \nrightarrow x$, and – consequently – that $T$ is closed.

---

Is my line of reasoning correct?
It is really a trivial matter, but I would like to be sure about it.

As always, looking forward to any feedback.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $T$ is not closed, then $S \setminus T$ contains a limit point of $T$. Call this limit point $x$. Because it is a limit point of $T$, we can construct a subsequence of $(x_m)$ which converges to $x$ (proof?), contradicting the assumption that $(x_m)$ has no such subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The err in you reasoning is that you are assuming the the sequence is closed in order to conclude that $x_{m_k}\not\to x$.

Note that the proof is not claiming that $(x_m)$ is closed, but rather that it is *a closed subset of $S$*. This is a subtle difference. This means that $(x_m)$ is closed with respect to the subspace topology on $S$. So we are considering $S$ as its own metric space without any regard to any points outside of it. If there are no convergent subsequences of $(x_m)$, then there simply does not exist $x$ such that $(x_{m_k})\to x$. Thus, the hypotheses for being closed are vacuously satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One point: you state *"If there are no convergent subsequences of $(x_m)$, then there simply does not exist $x$ such that $(x_{m_k})\to x$. Thus, the hypotheses for being closed are vacuously satisfied."* But the fact is that we don't say that there are no convergent subsequences in general, but simply that there are no convergent subsequences in $S$. That's why I actually find Bungo's comment clearer.

Comment: But if we are considering $S$ separate from any ambient space (which we may when we are viewing $(x_m)$ as a subset of $S$), then there are indeed no convergent subsequences of $(x_m)$.